# How to create new property in google analytics using javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is my first time using analytics api to create new property

I got the below code from here
[developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert)

```js
window.onload = function insertProperty() {
  var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.insert(
    {
      'accountId': '123456789',
      'resource': {
        'websiteUrl': 'http://www.examplepetstore.com',
        'name': 'Example Store'
      }
    });
  request.execute(function (response) { console.log(response);});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

when i run the code with valid account id ex:'123456789'

I am getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'analytics') at insertProperty

what should i do to create new property using this code

The below code is the setup of authorization and rest code

```js
  // Replace with your client ID from the developer console.
  var CLIENT_ID = '';

  // Set authorized scope.
  var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];


  function authorize(event) {
    // Handles the authorization flow.
    // `immediate` should be false when invoked from the button click.
    var useImmdiate = event ? false : true;
    var authData = {
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      immediate: useImmdiate
    };

    gapi.auth.authorize(authData, function(response) {
      var authButton = document.getElementById('auth-button');
      if (response.error) {
        authButton.hidden = false;
      }
      else {
        authButton.hidden = true;
        queryAccounts();
      }
    });
  }


function queryAccounts() {
  // Load the Google Analytics client library.
  gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3').then(function() {

    // Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
    gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list().then(handleAccounts);
  });
}


function handleAccounts(response) {
  // Handles the response from the accounts list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first Google Analytics account.
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for properties.
    queryProperties(firstAccountId);
  } else {
    console.log('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProperties(accountId) {
  // Get a list of all the properties for the account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list(
      {'accountId': accountId})
    .then(handleProperties)
    .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProperties(response) {
  // Handles the response from the webproperties list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {

    // Get the first Google Analytics account
    var firstAccountId = response.result.items[0].accountId;

    // Get the first property ID
    var firstPropertyId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query for Views (Profiles).
    queryProfiles(firstAccountId, firstPropertyId);
  } else {
    console.log('No properties found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryProfiles(accountId, propertyId) {
  // Get a list of all Views (Profiles) for the first property
  // of the first Account.
  gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
      'accountId': accountId,
      'webPropertyId': propertyId
  })
  .then(handleProfiles)
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}


function handleProfiles(response) {
  // Handles the response from the profiles list method.
  if (response.result.items && response.result.items.length) {
    // Get the first View (Profile) ID.
    var firstProfileId = response.result.items[0].id;

    // Query the Core Reporting API.
    queryCoreReportingApi(firstProfileId);
  } else {
    console.log('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
  }
}


function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
  // Query the Core Reporting API for the number sessions for
  // the past seven days.
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  })
  .then(null, function(err) {
      // Log any errors.
      console.log(err);
  });
}

  // Add an event listener to the 'auth-button'.
  document.getElementById('auth-button').addEventListener('click', authorize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello Analytics - A quickstart guide for JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="auth-button" hidden>Authorize</button>

<h1>Hello Analytics</h1>

<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>


<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

yes i did , when i click on Authorize i got this Error {error: {code: 403, message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",…}}

not sure why..?

Comment: Check if response is null response other wise i am not convinced that error message is coming from that code.   That is not a google error that is a JavaScript error.

Comment: i am not getting any response because i am getting this error on line 2 saying : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'analytics')  at insertProperty 
i checked manytimes its the same function from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert

Comment: That may be the same function but did you set up the authorization and the rest of the code [Managment api javascript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js)

Comment: yes i did , when i click on Authorize i got this Error 
{error: {code: 403, message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",…}}
not suew why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google

The issue is that your project is still in testing, you need to add users who you want to grant permission to test your app.

Go to google cloud console  Under consent screen look for the button that says "add Users" add the email of the user you are trying to run the app with.

[image]

Comment: yes i did , again  when i click on Authorize i got this Error 
{error: {code: 403, message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",…}}
not sue why..

Comment: error: {code: 403, message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",…}

code: 403

details: [{@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",…}]

errors: [{message: "Insufficient Permission", domain: "global", reason: "insufficientPermissions"}]

message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"

i haven't chnaged any code not sure why..

Comment: i have denied the permission for accessing data
when i cleared the cache and reloded it asked for permissions and i allow all and it workd now thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Understanding Property, Account, and View in Google Analytics
Your Analytics profile consists of 3 different components. They are account, property, and view (if you’re using Universal Analytics).

Here’s a closer look at each of them:

Account: You should have at least one account to access the analytics report.
Property: A property can be a website or a mobile app that you’d like to track in Google Analytics and has a unique tracking ID.
View: A view is the access point for your reports if you’re using Universal Analytics. For example, within a property you can have different views for viewing all the data for your website, viewing only a specific subdomain, like blog.example.com, or viewing only Google Ads traffic. Views do not exist in Google Analytics 4.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).